# selenium xpath to access various columns links in table

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

I'm trying to create selenium xpath for various column links in table. Each row is uniquely identified. In each row I know name of one column(name of product) and based on product name I'm trying to find other links in table to perform other operation on that product, such as change start and end date and remove the product etc.

Can some one shed a light creating xpath for each column in table. Table names appears as follows :

```
tooltip nameofprodduct percentage startdate enddate checkbox1 checkbox2 remove

<tr id="225259">

<td><a class="tooltip "><img alt="info" src="media/tooltip.gif" class="tooltip"><div style="display: none;"></a></td>

<td>name(299106)</td>

<td><div class="increse"><div style="display: none;" class="slidermetrics"></div><span onclick="showBoostSlider(225259,0,0,0,0);" class="increse">0%</span></td>

<td nowrap="nowrap" class="start"><span class="nonEdit"><span class="pointer">none</span><a href="#" class="ui-corner-all ui-button-small"><span class="icon-date"></span></a></span><span style="display: none;" class="edit"><input type="text" value="" style="width: 80px; margin-right: 7px;" class="inlineCalendarDisplay"><input type="hidden" value="" class="inlineCalendar"><a href="#" class="close"><span class="icon-cancel"></span></a><a href="#" class="save"><span class="icon-disk"></span></a></span><span class="tablesorterHiddenSortData"></span></td>

<td nowrap="nowrap" class="end"><span class="nonEdit"><span class="pointer">none</span><a href="#" class="ui-corner-all ui-button-small"><span class="icon-date"></span></a></span><span style="display: none;" class="edit"><input type="text" value="" style="width: 80px; margin-right: 7px;" class="inlineCalendarDisplay"><input type="hidden" value="" class="inlineCalendar"><a href="#" class="close"><span class="icon-cancel"></span></a><a href="#" class="save"><span class="icon-disk"></span></a></span><span class="tablesorterHiddenSortData"></span></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" onchange="switchEnabled('PEnabled',this,'225259');" checked="checked"></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" onchange="switchEnabled('SEnabled',this,'225259');" checked="checked"></td>

<td><a onclick="$('#tab3 &gt; table.jsonTable').rGrid('remove',225259); return false;" href="#">remove</a></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for this XPath which returns all links of all rows of all tables with given name:

```
 "//table/tr/td[.='name(299106)']/..//a"
```

To access the columns of a specific row, you can use:

```
 "//table/tr[id='225259']/td"
```

Comment: hi empo, thanks for your response however I'm looking for xpath which allows me to access each column in row which allow me to perform different operation by accessing column link text in a unique row

Comment: what do you mean? What nodes do you want select?

Comment: sorry if I'm confusing you. So here's simple version of what I'm looking. my table contains 8 different columns for each row(html code in previous posting). I want xpath that allow me to access each column for specific row. for example ...first column in each row contains "tooltip" link(upon accessing this link it shows summary of row), second column data is product name link, third column data is some other link. So we need xpath for accessing each column data that is displayed as link

Comment: I've added to the question the XPath  to select all columns of a specific row.